# Is this kind of routing bad practice? (Node.js + Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Basically, I have a route for SQL queries on my node.js backend but I don't want to make a separate route for each type of query - is it okay (good/bad practice?) to have all queries go to the same route and use a conditional statement to determine what kind of query you want to execute?

For example in pseudocode-ish javascript:

```
app.post('/query/:type', (req,res)=>{
   if(req.params.querytype === "all")
        execute sql query('SELECT * FROM TABLE');
   else if(req.body.querytype === "surname")
        execute sql query(`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.SURNAME = '${req.body.surname}' `
   else if(req.body.querytype === "STATUS")
        execute sql query(`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.STATUS = '${req.body.status'`)

   res.send("success");
})
```

How does this implementation compare with having a separate route for each query type?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine to have one route branch based on parameters in the URL or the form as long as the family of operations you're selecting from logically fits with that route and that verb.  But, if you're trying to compare the value of `:type` in your url, that would be `req.params.type`, not `req.body.querytype`.

Comment: Are they querying the same `TABLE` (and provide different filtering options), or are they different entities?

Comment: They very much look like different, independent routes. "*I don't want to make a separate route for each*" - why?